# How to set the Server to redirecting URL for inactive connections

Tags: java, redirect, connection, timeout, webserver

I am creating a mini web server in java, which will display the clients IP and some host information every time a new connection is made. I want to add a condition that the server will automatically redirect to default url Ex: "localhost/home.html" if a connection is inactive for 5 minutes. I got the code below from Internet. And i guess, it will do the redirecting part. What is the code that can check connection inactive status? And how i can insert that code inside this redirect code?

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class UrlRedirect extends HttpServlet {

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {
    String contextPath= "localhost/home.html";
response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(contextPath + "/maps"));
}
}
```

Comment: As i searched in stack, i really cannot find similar topics as mine. If there is already a similar question is answered, please give me the link.

Comment: I'm not certain what you're asking; if the connection is inactive there isn't a client to "redirect".

Comment: "Web Server will redirect to any URL if the connection is inactive for 5 minutes" This is the condition that I want to implement.

Comment: The server can't send redirects or indeed do anything if the connection is inactive, except close it. The question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

1. This logic should be at client side i.e. JavaScript rather than server side.
2. Write a JS/JQuery function which waits for a certain time and opens URL X.
3. Include the JS in the all the web pages.

theexamtime.com